# How do I extract the data from a query in Golang's GORM in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to read the data from a database with GoLang's GORM, and am new to Go in general. This is the snippet I'm trying to get work. It's to search a database using a number and check if it already exists. Just grasping at straws here, and not really understanding how GORM works, and can't find documentation that explains what to do after doing a Where Clause.

```
res := db.Where("Number = ?", inumber).First(&Profile{})
log.Print("Searched for profile")
if res.RecordNotFound() {
    log.Print("Record not found")
    return "", "", "", false
} else {
    log.Print("RES")

    log.Print(res.Rows())
    ret := res.Scan(&Profile{})
    return
}
return
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to retrieve data into some variable to be able to use it later:

```
p := Profile{}
res := db.Where("Number = ?", inumber).First(&p)

// now use p
log.Printf("%+v", p)
```

Comment: Yeah, got it figured out!

var person Profile

res := db.Find(&person, &Profile{Number: inumber})

return person.Name, person.Number, person.Address, true

Were the key parts. I just didn't really understand how the db.Where was working, and that it would be saved like that. Still wrapping my head around no objects.